# file upload and renamed without extension

Tags: php

I have a php upload script. And it is working fine. I only want to know if the way i am saving my picture is safe and it will display on all browsers.    Let say i uploaded:     `image.gif`    then i saved it to upload folder as:      `2ad25adt4mt2`    i.e     `<img src="/upload/2ad25adt4mt2" alt="pho">`        notice that there isn't an extension. Though It displays on my  current browser. Just want to know if it will display on all browser if my site is viewed.

Comment: Can I ask why you wouldn't want the extension there?

Comment: I thought that is good for security reasons?

Comment: I cannot think of anything that would make providing an extension to something less secure. The information regarding its "type" is embedded in the data of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) to see what your site looks like on other browsers and computers, however it is typically considered best practice to include file extensions as they are what tell the computer "hey this is an image/text/whatever file and you need to open it with program X".

As far as I know, there are no security benefits that leaving off the file extension gives you.